# Switch order of arguments for instance declaration in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to make an instance declaration, but the free type variable is not the last variable. For example, I have a class declaration

```
class Poppable m where
  tryPop :: m a -> Maybe (a, m a)
```

Now I want to make Q.PSQ (priority queue) an instance of Poppable. Specifically I want something like this:

```
instance (Ord p) => Poppable (\a -> Q.PSQ a p) where
  tryPop = fmap (first Q.key) . Q.minView
```

However, this is not legal Haskell code. If the order of arguments to PSQ were switched, then I would have no problem:

```
instance (Ord p) => Poppable (Q.PSQ p) where
  tryPop = fmap (first Q.key) . Q.minView
```

How do I switch the order of arguments for the instance declaration?

Now I could wrap PSQ with a newtype:

```
newtype PSQ'' a b = PSQ'' (Q.PSQ b a)
```

However this seems clunky to me because I have to constantly wrap/unwrap it. Is there an easier way?

*

I tried using data/type families, but both give errors.

(1) Using a data family declaration:

```
data family PSQ' a b
data instance PSQ' a b = PSQ b a
instance (Ord p) => Poppable (PSQ' p) where
  tryPop = fmap (first Q.key) . Q.minView
```

However this gives the error

```
Couldn't match type `Q.PSQ a p0' with `PSQ' p a'
```

even though they can match by setting p=p0.

(2) Type families won't work either.

```
type family PSQ' a b where
  PSQ' b a = Q.PSQ a b
```

gives

```
Illegal type synonym family application in instance: PSQ' p
```

Answer (score 8):

> Now I could wrap PSQ with a newtype:
>
> ```
> newtype PSQ'' a b = PSQ'' (Q.PSQ b a)
> ```
>
> However this seems clunky to me because I have to constantly wrap/unwrap it. Is there an easier way?

Nope, not really. You could, of course, write your `Poppable` class to make it match `PSQ`. And if you like, you can generalize your newtype to

```
newtype Flip f a b = Flip (f b a)
```

at which point you could write

```
instance Poppable (Flip Q.PSQ a)
```

but none of this will get rid of the underlying annoyance factor. There are reasons Haskell doesn't support this (apparently, it makes inference much harder, sometimes impossible, etc.), so you'll just have to deal with it.

P.S., that type synonym may be more useful poly-kinded, with `{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}`, where it ends up meaning

```
newtype Flip (f :: k1 -> k2 -> *) (a :: k2) (b :: k1) = Flip (f b a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply abandon parametricity and use a type family to project whichever argument correspond to the 'element type':

```
class Poppable q where
  type Elem q 
  tryPop :: q -> Maybe (Elem q, q)

data PSQ a p = ... 

instance Ord p => Poppable (PSQ a p) where 
  type Elem (PSQ a p) = a 
  tryPop = ...
```

Note this is a more general formulation, but it may be harder to work with.